# Redirecting with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It seems a very eask task, but I couldn't make it for hours after reading too much tutorial. Please help..

I need to redirect

```
http://example.com/myfolder/myfile.php?type=1&add=20
```

to this address:

```
http://example.com/newfolder/mytasks.xml
```

I tried too many. My last tryout was this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/myfolder/myfile.php?type=1&add=20$ /newfolder/mytasks.xml [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what www server add the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+myfolder/myfile\.php\?type=1&add=20 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newfolder/mytasks.xml [R=301,L]
```

#### Remember:

- RewriteRule match doesn't start with a slash `/`
- RewriteRule doesn't match query string, it matches only Request URI

Answer (score 1):

If you also want the query `type=1&add=20` removed, something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  type=1&add=20                 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !/newfolder/                  [NC]
RewriteRule ^myfolder/myfile\.php  /newfolder/mytasks.xml? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Redirects:

`http://example.com/myfolder/myfile.php?type=1&add=20` to

`http://example.com/newfolder/mytasks.xml`

For silent mapping, replace [R=301,NC,L] with [NC,L]